# How to display children of a specific parent on change of dropdown from a json in angular - 6

Tags: html, angular

Here I have a dropdown and and mock json contains array of objectr and also children as array.Here when I change the dropdown,specific children/sublink should be display on p tag, by onchange of specific project name.for Ex- if I select Project1 then sublink(Project1a", "Project1b"..) should display in p tag again on change of Project2 sublink(Project2a", "Project2b"..) should display/overwrite again. I tried in angularjs(https://plnkr.co/edit/0ZqtlLsKI5l7my5UpeFS?p=preview) But in angular6 I am not getting how to write ng option.Can anyone please help me,below is my code.

```
 <select [ngModel]="popData">
       <option *ngFor="let x of records" >{{x.project_name}}</option>
    </select>
<p>{{popData.sublink}}</p>
```

Its not working

Comment: The code in the question is Angular 6; the code in the PLNKR is AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

You should use bidirectional binding

```
[(ngModel)]="popData"
```